# Regular Expression to Scrape Specific Link

Tags: regex

For example, I want to get blogspot link from this page:

```
https://www.blogger.com/profile/12468507087713639596
```

I want to get results:

```
http://disneyenickdd.blogspot.com/
http://ellenesa-baccalaureate1.blogspot.com/
http://feminicesoutravessuras.blogspot.com/
...
```

I am trying to use regular expression like this:

```
(?<=href=")http.*?blogspot.com/(?=")
```

But I am getting broken link contents like this:

```
http://blogname.com/">All Contents<a/> <a href="bla bla bla... blogspot.com/
```

I stuck in this code, please help.
Thanks.

Comment: @XOR I want to get blogspot link, no other link or contents

Comment: like this : http://disneyenickdd.blogspot.com/

Comment: Sorry, but why do you need a regex? Can you use an HTML parser? What are you scraping with? Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this should work for you :

```
(http://[\w ]+[-?[\w ]+]?\.blogspot.com/)
```

PS: Do not forget to **escape the characters.**

And you can fetch the websites with the help of **numbered groups**.

> > here:
>
> the content is extracted between the http and .blogspot.com

This also has capabilities to extract the links which has "-" between them.

Comment: Thank you so much, god bless you :D